# HTML Help keyword location

Tags: indexing, chm

I'm writing a manual and some important keywords are repeated in several pages. In the project's index I defined the keywords like this:

```
<LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Name" value="Stackoverflow">
    <param name="Name" value="Overview">
    <param name="Local" value="overview.html#stackoverflow">
    <param name="Name" value="Cover">
    <param name="Local" value="cover.html#stackoverflow">
    <param name="Name" value="Intro">
    <param name="Local" value="intro.html#stackoverflow">
    </OBJECT>
```

It works but instead of the title the dialog shows the keyword and the name of the project repeated three times.

Here's how it looks: http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/3342/sokeywordjs9.png

How can I display the tile of the page that contains the keyword in that dialog? I would like to show like this:

```
Stackoverflow  Overview
Stackoverflow  Cover
Stackoverflow  Intro
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How can I display the tile of the page
>   that contains the keyword in that
>   dialog?

You can't. The Location column in the Topics Found dialog always contains the name of the source chm file of the topic. The only way to get around this is to use modular help, which comes with it's own share of problems and overhead.

The search and indexing features don't gracefully support topics with the same title within the same project. This seems shortsighted, but HTMLHelp is now over ten years old, so maybe they just planned to fix it later and never got around to it.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to HTMLHelp out there?